# Can't set WorkspaceProject root folder as project directory

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-developer-studio

In Liferay Developer Studio I have created Liferay modules in the past, but now I can't seem to be able to create any:

[image]

Whatever the name I enter, I am told:

```
Can't set WorkspaceProject root folder as project directory.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project cannot be inside liferay-workspace, it is its base folder. It needs to be inside **theme** or **modules folder**.

Then it will a create project for you over there once you click finish.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with Liferay Developer Studio 3.1.2.
If you set your Liferay Workspace to be the same as the Eclipse workspace, you will face this issue.
I solved the problem by:
deleting the default "liferay-workspace" and then creating a "workspaces" folder for Eclipse and a "Workspace1" folder for liferay (within Studio).
Within Studio, the root folder is now called "Workspace1" and I can set up gradle.properties to specify where the plugins should be deployed.
Modules can be created without issues now.